# If $\alpha=x_1x_2x_3$ and $\beta=y_1y_2y_3$ be 2 three digit numbers then number of pairs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\beta\geq\alpha$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> If $\alpha=x_1x_2x_3$ and $\beta=y_1y_2y_3$ be 2 three digit numbers then number of pairs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\beta\geq\alpha$

Starting from $\alpha=100$, $\beta=100,101,102,...,999$. $\beta$ has 900 values. Similarly for each $\alpha$, $\beta$ has $1000-\alpha$ values. Hence, total number of pairs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\sum_{100}^{999}1000-\alpha$. But the answer given is $45*(55)^2$. How?

Comment: Maybe digits are different ?

Comment: @openspace not mentioned in the question...